# NetworkX ego_graph not using the distance setting correctly with radius

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, dijkstra

I'm trying to use the `ego_graph` to draw some networks focused on a set of randomly chosen nodes.  If I don't set the `distance` parameters, then it correctly returns the graph within `thisRadius` steps; however, when I do specify the distance, the results are completely wrong and don't make any sense.

> How do I use the `distance` feature of `nx.ego_graph` correctly?

In my case, I have various weights on my edges, but the one I want to use now is the traversal time in minutes called `timeWeight`.  Let's say I want a subgraph of all the nodes within 30 minutes of my starting node.  I expected

```
nodeCenteredSubgraph = nx.ego_graph(thisNetwork, egoID, radius=30, distance='timeWeight')
```

would return this, but instead it returns nodes which are MUCH further away than 30 minutes.  The radius does have some effect though, because if I decrease it to `radius=1` I get a smaller (but still huge) subgraph...and certainly more nodes than can be reached in 1 minute.  In fact I should have gotten just the ego in that case.

If I set `radius=0.1` or `radius=0.01` or smaller I always get the same thing, and although much smaller than before, it still returns a fairly large graph...much more than can be reached in less than a minute (nothing).

Realizing that the `ego_graph` uses `single_source_dijkstra` as its base, I tried that function directly with

```
distances,paths = nx.single_source_dijkstra(thisNetwork, egoID, target=None, cutoff=10, weight='timeWeight')
```

and it returns a bunch of nodes with weights from 0.0 to 10.0 (all integers though they shouldn't be if it were actually using `timeWeight`) and thye have nothing to do with the timeWeight values.

From the documentation it seems I'm doing it right, and I can't find a single example of using the distance parameter with `ego_graph`, so hopefully somebody can tell me what I've got wrong.

Comment: Can you give an example, showing a simple graph and showing what the edge attributes are?  I don't see anything obviously wrong with your function call, so I'm wondering whether it's the underlying graph or something with the networkx method.

Comment: @Joel: While preparing a data sample I discovered the problem...somewhere in my pipeline some timeWeights had become zeros, thus allowing large graph results even when the minutes value was 0.1.  The results still don't make sense in light of that, but after fixing that it seems to be okay.